# When before the open page show "Null check operator used on a null value" and after fetch from data base and show in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

In my code fetch data and show nicely but before open the that page show this error and after show those details.In my code fetch data from firebase array type data and string type data.

error

[image]

after that error page opening and fetch data prefect

[image]

**model code**

```
class Details {
  String? id;
  String? email;
  String? age;
  String? familyChildren;
  List<String>? drinkstalkSE;
  List<String>? drinksUnderstandSE;
  List<String>? drinksUnderstandSE2;

  Details(
      {this.id,
      this.email,
      this.age,
      this.familyChildren,
      this.drinkstalkSE,
      this.drinksUnderstandSE,
      this.drinksUnderstandSE2});

  Details.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    email = json['email'];
    age = json['age'];
    familyChildren = json['familyChildren'];
    drinksUnderstandSE = json['drinksUnderstandSE'].cast<String>();
    drinkstalkSE = json['drinkstalkSE'].cast<String>();
    drinksUnderstandSE2 = json['drinksUnderstandSE2'].cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['age'] = this.age;
    data['familyChildren'] = this.familyChildren;

    data['drinksUnderstandSE'] = this.drinksUnderstandSE;
    data['drinkstalkSE'] = this.drinkstalkSE;
    data['drinksUnderstandSE2'] = this.drinksUnderstandSE2;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**backend code**

```
 Details oneUserDetails = Details();
  Future<void> getDetails() async {
    final sp = context.read<SignInProvider>();

    print(sp.uid);
    final snapshot =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('${sp.uid}').get();

    final result = await snapshot.then(
        (snap) => snap.data() == null ? null : Details.fromJson(snap.data()!));
    print('result is ====> $result');
    setState(() {
      oneUserDetails = result!;
      loading = false;
    });
```

How to remove that error showing before the page open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oneUserDetails` is defines as `nullable` variable and its may be null but you use `!` in `Text` widget when try to access `drinksUnderstandSE` or other property which is wrong because by using `!` you said I'm pretty sure it is not null which it is, so change `!` to `?`:

```
Text( 'drink understand : ${oneUserDetails?.drinksUnderstandSE}'), // this will show like this => drink understand : null
```

or you can set default value to avoid showing null, like this:

```
Text( 'drink understand : ${oneUserDetails?.drinksUnderstandSE ?? 'default variable'}'), // this will show like this => drink understand : default variable
```

Comment: Thank you bro.  but I tried to pass uid to firebase query but that's not passing I will edit the question

Comment: @DasunDola glad to help.  I think that is an other issue, try ask new question and use firebase tag so other guys who are expert in it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Details? oneUserDetails;

Change this to:

```
  Details oneUserDetails = Details();
```

Comment: Thank you That's worked .. can you explain reason for that

Comment: initially your oneUserDetails is null unit it get data from server which takes some time . now when you are calling Details oneUserDetails = Details(); is Empty Object not null